# ERROR 2003 on MYSQL 5.1 on Openshift

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

Today, I have problem on my openshift account. Mysql on my openshift account gone rogue, i cant connect to MySql by php script and even from SSH.

Already try to restart the gear, but it's not working.When i try to SSH to the gear.And when i type MYSQL. It have this error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server

Can someone show me how to fix this issue ? thanks

Comment: Read this: [*Can't connect to \[local\] MySQL server*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to do the following from the command line:

1) rhc app-force-stop {your app name}

2) rhc app-start {your app name}

Seems like something is stuck and you need a "hard" restart